# Dynamically Parsing JSON with Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, coding-efficiency, dynamic-code

I have a JSON document pulled back from a support system API. With my code, I want to pull out the pre-configured fields dynamically, presuming that the JSON may have more or fewer of the desired fields when my program calls the API.

I have some code that works, though it seems very convoluted and inefficient.

Here is a snippet of the pieces of JSON that I'm interested in:

```
{
   "rows": [
      {
         "assignee_id": 1,
         "created": "2017-01-25T14:13:19Z",
         "custom_fields": [],
         "fields": [],
         "group_id": 2468,
         "priority": "Low",
         "requester_id": 2,
         "status": "Open",
         "subject": "Support request",
         "ticket": {
            "description": "Ticket descritpion",
            "id": 1000,
            "last_comment": {
               "author_id": 2,
               "body": "Arbitrary text",
               "created_at": "2017-02-09T14:21:38Z",
               "public": false
            },
            "priority": "low",
            "status": "open",
            "subject": "Support request",
            "type": "incident",
            "url": "Arbitrary URL"
         },
         "updated": "2017-02-09T14:21:38Z",
         "updated_by_type": "Agent"
      },
      {
         "assignee_id": 1,
         "created": "2017-02-09T14:00:18Z",
         "custom_fields": [],
         "fields": [],
         "group_id": 3579,
         "priority": "Normal",
         "requester_id": 15,
         "status": "Open",
         "subject": "Change request",
         "ticket": {
            "description": "I want to change this...",
            "id": 1001,
            "last_comment": {
               "author_id": 20,
               "body": "I want to change the CSS on my website",
               "created_at": "2017-02-09T14:12:12Z",
               "public": true
            },
            "priority": "normal",
            "status": "open",
            "subject": "Change request",
            "type": "incident",
            "url": "Arbitrary URL"
         },
         "updated": "2017-02-09T14:12:12Z",
         "updated_by_type": "Agent"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have an ArrayList called wantedFields that I build up from a config to define which information I want to pull out from the JSON:

```
  ["id","subject","requester_id","status","priority","updated","url"]
```

The complexity is that data is replicated in the API, and I only want to pull out data once, with a preference for the data in "rows" where applicable. My method for doing this is below. It feels like I'm repeating code but I can't really see how to make this work more efficiently. The JSON is held as "viewAsJson".

```
def ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> assignConfiguredFields(viewAsJson, wantedFields) {
    //Pull out configured fields from JSON and store as Map to write as CSV later
    ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> listOfDataToWrite = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>()

    ArrayList<String> rowKeyList = new ArrayList<String>()
    def validationRow = viewAsJson.rows.get(0)
    //Compare one row object to config first
    validationRow.each { k, v ->
        if (wantedFields.contains(k)) {
            wantedFields.remove(k)
            rowKeyList.add(k)
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> ticketKeyList = new ArrayList<String>()
    def validationTicket = viewAsJson.rows.ticket.get(0)

    //Compare one ticket object to config first
    validationTicket.each { k, v ->
        if (wantedFields.contains(k)) {
            wantedFields.remove(k)
            ticketKeyList.add(k)
        }
    }

    def rows = viewAsJson.rows
    def tickets = viewAsJson.rows.ticket

    //Pull matching ticket objects from JSON and store in Map

    ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> tickList= new ArrayList<>()
    ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> rowList= new ArrayList<>()
    rows.each { row ->
        Map<String,Object> rowMap = new HashMap<>()
        row.each { k, v ->
            if(rowKeyList.contains(k))
                rowMap.put(k,v)
        }
        rowList.add(rowMap)
    }

    tickets.each { ticket ->
        Map<String,Object> ticketMap = new HashMap<>()
        ticket.each { k, v ->
            if(ticketKeyList.contains(k))
                ticketMap.put(k, v)
        }
        tickList.add(ticketMap)
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowList.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String,Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>()
        dataMap.putAll(rowList.get(i))
        dataMap.putAll(tickList.get(i))
        listOfDataToWrite.add(dataMap)
    }

    println listOfDataToWrite
    return listOfDataToWrite
}
```

I know there should be some validation for if the wantedFields ArrayList is still populated. I've iterated on this code so many times I just forgot to re-add that this time.

Comment: so given that Json, and the list of keys `["id","subject","requester_id","status","priority","updated","url"]`, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: From the example JSON
`["id":1000,"subject":"Support request", "requester_id":2,"status":"open","priority":"low","updated":"2017-02-09T14:21:38Z","url":"Arbitrary URL"]`

I've realised a blunder in the code though - I'm just fixing that now.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed the code now. I'm expecting it to iterate through the JSON and pull out the configured data from each item in the "rows" array. EG:

`[["id":1000,"subject":"Support request", "requester_id":2,"status":"Open","priority":"Low","updated":‌​"2017-02-09T14:21:38‌​Z","url":"Arbitrary URL"],["id":1001,"subject":"Change request", "requester_id":15,"status":"Open","priority":"Normal","updated":‌​"2017-02-09T14:12:12Z","url":"Arbitrary URL"]]`

Comment: And I've found yet more mistakes. I've edited the OP which now returns the desired output by using a third map to merge the parsed information into. 

This does lead me to believe that the process could be done a little bit more elegantly though, but I'm still struggling to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still need this code but why not try something like this.
Have a translation map and run each row through it.

```
Object tranverseMapForValue(Map source, String keysToTranverse, Integer location = 0){
    List keysToTranverseList = keysToTranverse.split(/\./)
    tranverseMapForValue(source, keysToTranverseList, location)
}
Object tranverseMapForValue(Map source, List keysToTranverse, Integer location = 0){
    if(source.isEmpty() || keysToTranverse.isEmpty()){
        return null
    }

    String key = keysToTranverse[location]
    if(source[key] instanceof Map){
        return tranverseMapForValue(source[key], keysToTranverse, location + 1)
    }
    else{
        return source[key]
    }
}


Map translation = [
    "ticket.id": "id",
    "ticket.subject": "subject",
    "requester_id": "requester_id",
    "ticket.status": "status",
    "priority": "priority",
    "updated": "updated",
    "ticket.url": "url"
]

List rows = []

json.rows.each{ row ->
    Map mapForRow = [:]

    translation.each{ sourceKey, newKey ->
        mapForRow << [(newKey): tranverseMapForValue(row, sourceKey)]
    }

    rows.add(mapForRow)
}
```

Comment: I'm no longer working on this, but I understand the process of what you're suggesting and it makes sense. No doubt it will be handy in the future!